# Automapper generates left join in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm using Automapper in my .NET Core 2.2 back-end service. I use `ProjectTo` method to generate my result.

This is my `Product` class:

```
public class Product 
{
    public DateTime? SellEndDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool AllowToShow { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public Guid BrandId { get; set; }
}
```

And it is the result class:

```
public class Dto 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CategoryDto Category { get; set;}
    public BrandDto Brand { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration in the profile is a normal one. The generated SQL statement for category table has `Inner Join`, but for brand table it uses a `Left Join`.

Why is that?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html). But I would guess it's an EF decision.

Comment: It has to be EF Core configuration issue. AutoMapper has nothing in common with SQL joins. You can verify that by replacing `ProjectTo` with manual `Select`.

Comment: Share us the defination for `Category` and `Brand `. What is the EF Core query?

Comment: @TaoZhou I just use ProjectTo<> extension method.the category and brand are the same with guid primary key.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu  Hey guys. it's a ef core decision. In fluent api the category relationship is required and it uses inner join and for brand that is not required it uses left join. Don't know why is that yet....